# Formatting two field values into a single column with markup - can't get markup to work

Tags: sharepoint-online, html, json-formatting, column-formatting, markup

I have a list with two column values needed.  One is a description - the other a URL.

I want to format my description field, such that the URL displays beneath the description.

i.e.:
Description text fills the cell, wraps, looks pretty.

http://hyperlink_to_reference_site.com/SomeURI

I've tried multiple DIVS, SPANS, even something simple such as the following:

```
"txtContent": "$currentField + '</br>' + [$URI]"
```

This last one doesn't show the URI and I actually see the  rather than having that treated as markup.

Can anyone help!!!!

Comment: Is your description is multiple lines of text ? is it plain or rich text field? Also what is data type of your URI field?

Comment: Also, to access the current column value you need to use `@currentField` and not `$currentField`.

Comment: I mistyped that.  I am using @currentField.  The content is plain text - not RTF and is multi-line.  URI is a hyperlink field.  So - I'm trying to display URI.desc.

NOTE:  I tried creating 3 child elmTypes one for the Description text, one for the BR and one for the URL --- the BR does nothing, and the URI div basically splits the column into two parts side-by-side.

Answer (score 2):

Try below JSON code:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "= @currentField + '\n\n' + [$URI]"
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Update From Comments**:

**Note**: Please note `=` and `+` used in `txtContent` property in above JSON. We need to use it as we are writing "expression" to concatenate two fields.

Try following JSON code.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "style": {
        "display": "block"
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "txtContent": "@currentField"
        },
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "children": [
                {
                    "elmType": "a",
                    "txtContent": "[$URI.desc]",
                    "attributes": {
                        "target": "_blank",
                        "href": "[$URI]"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Try this JSON code for simple formatting which combines two fields and separate them with new line. note that you need to use `\n` instead of `<br/>`.

Comment: Nope -- this results in @currentField being interpreted as a string rather than evaluating to the content of the field.   The \n works to create a new line.   But now the field reference is translated as absolute text.

Comment: This is working fine for me. can you please check if you are making any spelling mistake?  `@currentField` is camel-case . check output in updated answer.

Comment: I updated this as "@currentField\n\n[$URI]" and that got closer - but still the @ and $ field references to displaying as this text, rather than evaluating the actual field content.

Comment: Here's my actual JSON:

{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "debugMode": true,
  "txtContent": "@currentField\n\n[$URI]",
  "style": {
    "font-family": "Arial, Tahoma",
    "font-size": "12pt",
    "width": "450px"
  }
}

Comment: You need to use `+` also to concatenate the two fields. can you please try by just copy pasting the code in answer and check if it works for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106832/discussion-between-jerzeyjenko-and-ganesh-sanap).

Answer (score 1):

This was a tricky one! Adding a top element with `"style": {"display": "block"}` and nesting the other elements in that did the trick:

```
{
"elmType": "div",
"style": {"display":"block"},
"children": [
    {
    "elmType": "div",
    "children": [
        { 
        "elmType": "span",
        "txtContent": "@currentField"
        }
        ]
    },
{
    "elmType": "a",
    "txtContent": "[$URI]",
    "attributes": {"href": "[$URI]"}
}
]}
```

Result:

[image]